# Adobe PDF Javascript to Extract Name, save file

Tags: javascript, adobe, filenames, acrobat

Looking for some help with Javascript in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI.

Here's what I have so far:

```
   /* Extract pages to file */
   // Regular expression used to acquire the base name of file

   var re = /\.pdf$/i;
   // filename is the base name of the file Acrobat is working on

   var filename = this.documentFileName.replace(re,"");

   try {for (var i = 0; i < this.numPages; i+=4)
         this.extractPages({
            nStart: i,
            nEnd: i+3,
         });         
   } catch (e) { console.println("Aborted: " + e) }
```

What happens now is that it extracts the page range and creates a series of open files that I can then rename.

What I'd like to do is add a loop to extract a name from the bill, then use that as the file name to create a new file in a folder.

I found this:

```
for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {
    // iterate over all words
    for (var n = 0; n < this.getPageNumWords(p); n++) {
        if (this.getPageNthWord(p, n) == stringToSearchFor) {
            pageArray.push(p);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

which I think will get me part of the way there, but I'm not sure how to include that in my loop.

I think I need to search the document a static string (in this case "Student Name") and then return the next two words.

Answer (score 0):

Worked up a file to do this sort of thing using copy-pasted code (and some help from Thom Parker on the Adobe Forums, see: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/step-by-step-instructions-for-saving-a-pdf-in-acrobat-dc-using-a-javascript/m-p/10893916?page=1#M238905)

```js
// https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-to-set-up-a-default-value-in-execdialog/td-p/9343585?page=1

var dialogTitle = "Please specify ";
var defaultAnswer = "";

var stringToSearchFor = app.response("Client ID",
dialogTitle, defaultAnswer);

//https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/print/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript/


/* Put script title here */

// Iterates over all pages and find a given string and extracts all 
// pages on which that string is found to a new file.

var pageArray = [];

//var stringToSearchFor = "64718";

for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {
 // iterate over all words
 for (var n = 0; n < this.getPageNumWords(p); n++) {
  if (this.getPageNthWord(p, n) == stringToSearchFor) {
   pageArray.push(p);
   break;
  }
 }
}

if (pageArray.length > 0) {
 // extract all pages that contain the string into a new document
 var d = app.newDoc();    // this will add a blank page - we need to remove that once we are done
 for (var n = 0; n < pageArray.length; n++) {
  d.insertPages( {
   nPage: d.numPages-1,
   cPath: this.path,
   nStart: pageArray[n],
   nEnd: pageArray[n],
  } );
 }

    // remove the first page
    d.deletePages(0);
    
// https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-to-save-as-pdf-form-using-script/td-p/9848947?page=1

// Split Path into an array so it is easy to work with
var aMyPath = this.path.split("/");

// Remove old file name
aMyPath.pop();

// Add new file name
aMyPath.push(stringToSearchFor);

// Put path back together and save
d.saveAs(aMyPath.join("/")+".pdf");

}
```